# Symfony 2.7. How to get/set value of the Form field after Form submission?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I want to set the value (unix timestamp) for the form hidden datetime element after the form submission, Symfony 2.7.

```
$starttimeStr=$form->get('meetingbundle_event[starttimeStr]');// here i intend to get user input for the date in string format
$dateObj = new \Datetime($starttimeStr); 
$starttimeInt=$dateObj->getTimestamp();
$form->get('meetingbundle_event[starttimeInt]')->setData($starttimeInt); //here i want to set  the datetime in decimal format
```

But this does not work, because nor id `meetingbundle_event_starttime`, nor name `meetingbundle_event[starttimeStr]` are not accepted as valid arguments for  `get(string $name`) of FormInterface:
http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/Form/FormInterface.html
I know name and id by using Tools-> WebDeveloperExtension->Forms->DisplayFormDetails in Firefox.

Thus i tried `$elem=$form->all();` to see what are the names of my form elements, but i can not see the result:

```
print_r($elem); // crashes web-browser
$fs->dumpFile('C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\proj2_27\form.txt', $elem ); */ Complains that there is no memory

$elemser=  serialize($elem); //gives error that  php can not serialize Closure

$elemjson = json_encode($elem);
$fs->dumpFile('C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\proj2_27\form.txt', $elemjson ); // outputs empty strings
```

What is the default naming rules for Form fields in order i could retrieve them using `$form->get('field_name')`?

Answer (score 1):

To get element value use `$form->getData()['%element_name%']`
As I know it is impossible to change submitted form element value explicit by calling `$form->setData()`. So if you want to change submitted form element value inside form use `FormBuilder` method `addViewTransformer` http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html  or do it in form event listener http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html.

Answer (score 0):

Found haw to get the child of form - use name from FormType class (not field id nor name in the form):

`$starttimeStr=$form->get('starttimeStr'); //where starttimeStr is the corresponding name of the field in Form class "\src\Bundle\Form\EventType.php"`.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('title', 'text', array(  'attr' => array( 'style' => 'width: 500px',), ) )
        ->add('keywords', 'text', array(  'attr' => array('style' => 'width: 500px',) ,) )
        ->add('starttime', 'hidden', array('data' => '0',) )
        ->add('endtime', 'hidden', array('data' => '0',) ) 
        ->add('starttimeStr') ...
```

But still i am not able to get the value.  `$starttimeStr` appears to be not the simple input date string (21-12-2015), but large array which crashes Firefox.

```
print_r($starttimeStr);// crashes Firefox.

$elemser=serialize('starttimeStr');
$fs->dumpFile('C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\proj2_27\form.txt', $elemser ); // outputs empty string "s:12:"starttimeStr";"
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally! One has to get field, than to get Data. It is not described in Official documentation.

$starttimeStr=$form->get('starttimeStr')->getData();

print_r($starttimeStr); // gives user input "21-12-2015 04:33 Europe/London".

Comment: Although i can get the data after the form submission in the controller, but i can not set them using `$form->get('starttimeInt')->setData($starttimeInt);`  I am getting error: `You cannot change the data of a submitted form`.  Is there are a way to go around this default behavior?

Comment: As @max-p stated, you will want to use a data transformer or an event listener to modify the data.