# How to set the data after the form submission?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

This is extension of the following question
[Symfony 2.7. How to get/set value of the Form field after Form submission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34297487/symfony-2-7-how-to-get-set-value-of-the-form-field-after-form-submission) .

I need to set the data of the form field in the controller after the form submission. This feature does not work. How to enable it? How to achieve this in other ways?

...\src\MeetingBundle\Form\EventType.php

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('starttimeInt', 'hidden', array('data' => '0',) )
        ->add('endtimeInt', 'hidden', array('data' => '0',) )
```

..\src\MeetingBundle\Controller\EventMapController.php

```
$starttimeInt=$dateObj->getTimestamp();
$form->get('starttimeInt')->setData($starttimeInt); 
$starttimeIntSet=$form->get('starttimeInt')->getData();
print_r($starttimeIntSet); // prints 0 instead of the timestamp

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush(); // starttimeInt column contains 0 instead of timestamp, which i want to add to the form after form submission
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34298142/5298034

Comment: Why don't you just call  $entity->setStarttimeInt()? If that doesn't work take a look at symfony's form events: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I have deleted my wrong answer and pasted your suggestion- i become tired after 13h of work ...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to set the data to the entity:

..\src\MeetingBundle\Controller\EventMapController.php

```
/**
 * Creates a new Event entity.
 *
 * @Route("/createjsmapV2", name="ev_jsMap_createV2")
 * @Method("POST|GET")
 * @Template("MeetingBundle:event:ev_jsMap_new.html.twig")
 */
public function createJsMapAction(Request $request)

    $entity = new Event();
    $form = $this->createCreateJsMapForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $starttimeInt=$dateObj->getTimestamp();
// form->get('starttimeInt')->setData($starttimeInt); // this will not work, you will find 0 in the database as it is the default value in FormType

//here you can set the data to any field you want to modify, after the user submitted the form
    $entity->setStarttimeInt($starttimeInt);
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();
```